# print notification array in Laravel - Illegal string offset

Tags: arrays, laravel, notifications, laravel-blade

I try to print some data from notification array.
when i print all array in blade:

```
@foreach ($user->userNotif() as $value)
    {{$value->data}}
@endforeach
```

then everything is fine. result:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "theme": "asdasd"
}
```

But if i try print 'id' from this array:

```
@foreach ($user->userNotif() as $value)
    {{$value->data['id']}}
@endforeach
```

I get the error:

```
Illegal string offset 'id'...
```

Help! what wrong with this array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not one hundred 100% sure, but I believe that data is an object and you need to access the id like so:

```
$value->data->id
```

As a disclaimer this hasn't been tested.

Hope this helps!

Comment: nope( error: "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: Do dd($value) in your view and tell show me what it returns